# How to change the style of Menu entry

Tags: css, javafx, stylesheet, fxml

I have created a Menu on my JavaFX application. Here i want to style the `RadioMenuItem` component:

[image: Sample]

How i can:

- Modify the `Arrow` to colorize the Background (Like [image])
- Hide only the `Arrow` completely

  // [...]

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS styles.

Background color (checked):

```
.radio-menu-item:checked > .left-container {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Arrow color:

```
.radio-menu-item:checked > .left-container > .radio {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Same color hides the arrow.

[image]